# How can I play pdf, Bulider and mp3 on android

Tags: android

i would create a programm, it reads pdf, bulider and mp3 on Android.
for Examples:
it´s in paris so it shows me the important places in Paris. it´s read from pdf file and show me builder as well as hear mp3, what i save in pdf file.

it´s possible or not?
could someone helpe me please?

thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service or a tutorial site. Show your attempted solution (code) and explain in what way it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To save something to pdf or to read from pdf you need to use pdf libraries. iText is one such option. Do check the licencing terms.Check this sample code : http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=12
  Incase you want to read out pdf loudly(You mentioned read from pdf) you need to use TTS engine.Android provides a TTS engine.
- What you mean by bulider?.. I do not have any knowledge.
- To play audio, you can use synthesizeToFile()and create an audio file that contains the TTS(Text to speech) output. Then, you would use a MediaPlayer object to play, pause, and stop playing the file.Here is the link to follow:http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

Comment: thanks man. i meant by builder, i have to save builder in my database or whereever and i have to read the builder from it and the programm show me all(PDF, MP3 and Builders). i have to choose the options. i can choose,what i want (PDF,MP3 or Builders)